# Add subviews with proportional width to scroll view

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a scroll view which contains three subviews which look like this:

[image]

The problem is that since the stack view which contains the label has 80% of the total width of the subview, this looks weird when the user scrolls the app:

[image]

As you can see, the views in the scroll view at the bottom don't look quite okay because of the 80% multiplier applied to the width constraint. The more the user scrolls the scroll view, the bigger the "offset". I want to keep the subviews always centered.

How do I keep the views centered while still keeping the 80% proportion?

Content inset:

```
slideScrollView.contentSize.width = view.bounds.width * CGFloat(introArray.count)
```

Subview setup:

```
slideScrollView.addSubview(introView)
introView.frame = CGRect(x: view.bounds.width * CGFloat(index), y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: slideScrollView.frame.height)
```

Stack view setup:

[image]

Comment: Can you show the constraints you have applied on the labels ?

Comment: I would place within the scroll view, three side-by-side full width subviews with no margin between them.  Each of those can then have an orange subview constrained to 80% with of it's parent.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong - The issues is - Labels are not centrally aligned ?

Comment: If that is so, set label width equal to that of stack view and set leading and trailing constraints to 0. Having said that, text should be centrally aligned

Comment: @Nitish your way works but I don't want them to be the same width of the view because it looks bad.

Comment: @danh I'm trying to understand your solution. That would seem to work!

Comment: Then keep the margin (say 10, both trailing and leading). But make sure they have horizontally centred constraint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this view hierarchy, where each line is the parent of the line below it...

```
|<------------contentSize.width---------->|  scroll view

|-----p0------|------p1-----|------p2-----|  pages

  |-------|      |--------|   |--------|     orange views, 80%

  |-------|      |--------|   |--------|     labels, center justified"
```

The key is adding the "pages" layer, that divide the scroll view content into thirds.  The orange views apply their 80% width to those.

Comment: This will not display the partial beginning and ending of the previous and the next card.

Answer (score 1):

For a banner I would use a `UIPageViewController`. Each controller for every page would have a `UIColor.clear` background, and the orange part would be its subview properly centered and aligned based on the controller's view.

Comment: this would be ok, but in my case I have a view that I want to "repeat". I don't want to duplicate the two labels in every single view controller of the page controller.

Comment: @Cesare I don't understand why you would have to duplicate anything.. you want to repeat two views? just create two instances of the given viewController.. but the choice is yours in the end :)